# Link C++ OSX (from Fortran) - Intel Compiler

Tags: c++, fortran, intel-fortran, icc

I am having a hard time linking C++ and Fortran using Intel compilers on OSX (10.9) and I really appreciate some help!

Previous related questions mainly talk about gfortran and don't address this issue in particular (link C++/Fortran with Intel compilers + Mac OSX + main in Fortran). Then, I strongly believe this is not a duplicate question.

The main program is in Fortran and for internal reasons I can't transfer the main to C++. So answers like "write the main in C++ and link the Fortran libraries" don't help.

One more piece of information: C++ code needs [gsl-gnu scientific library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) and  [CERN Minuit2](http://seal.web.cern.ch/seal/MathLibs/Minuit2/html/) package

C++ code is compile using the following flags

```
 icpc -c -O2 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -clangxx-name=clang++ -DHAVE_INLINE
```

where `-DHAVE_INLINE` is a flag needed by gsl for optimization

The link flag of the Fortran code is the following

```
F90CRLINK = -cxxlib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -lMinuit2
```

and the compiler/linker is ifort.

The error message in the linking process, which I can post if someone need to figure this out, suggest that `ifort` cannot find the C++ library.

Update 1: The error Message

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "__ZNKSt3__120__vector_base_commonILb1EE20__throw_length_errorEv", referenced from:
>         _minimizer in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__16vectorIdNS_9allocatorIdEEEC1ERKS3_ in min.o
>         __ZNK4ROOT7Minuit220BasicFunctionMinimum14UserParametersEv in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__16vectorIN4ROOT7Minuit215MinuitParameterENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE6assignIPS3_EENS_9enable_ifIXsr3std3__121__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeESA_SA_ in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__16vectorIjNS_9allocatorIjEEE6assignIPjEENS_9enable_ifIXsr3std3__121__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeES7_S7_ in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__16vectorIdNS_9allocatorIdEEE6assignIPdEENS_9enable_ifIXsr3std3__121__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeES7_S7_ in min.o
>     "__ZNKSt3__16locale9use_facetERNS0_2idE", referenced from:
>         _minimizer in min.o
>         __ZNK11MinFcnCosmoclERKNSt3__16vectorIdNS0_9allocatorIdEEEE in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__14endlIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_ in min.o
>     "__ZNKSt3__18ios_base6getlocEv", referenced from:
>         _minimizer in min.o
>         __ZNK11MinFcnCosmoclERKNSt3__16vectorIdNS0_9allocatorIdEEEE in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__14endlIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_ in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEmc", referenced from:
>         __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC1ERKS5_", referenced from:
>         __ZNSt3__16vectorIN4ROOT7Minuit215MinuitParameterENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE6assignIPS3_EENS_9enable_ifIXsr3std3__121__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeESA_SA_ in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED1Ev", referenced from:
>         __ZNSt3__113__vector_baseIN4ROOT7Minuit215MinuitParameterENS_9allocatorIS3_EEED1Ev in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc in min.o
>         __ZN4ROOT7Minuit216MnUserParametersD1Ev in min.o
>         __ZN4ROOT7Minuit220MnUserParameterStateD1Ev in min.o
>         __ZN4ROOT7Minuit28MnMigradD1Ev in min.o
>         __ZN4ROOT7Minuit219MnRefCountedPointerINS0_20BasicFunctionMinimumEE15RemoveReferenceEv in min.o
>         __ZNK4ROOT7Minuit220BasicFunctionMinimum14UserParametersEv in min.o
>         ...
>     "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEaSERKS5_", referenced from:
>         __ZNSt3__16vectorIN4ROOT7Minuit215MinuitParameterENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE6assignIPS3_EENS_9enable_ifIXsr3std3__121__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeESA_SA_ in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE3putEc", referenced from:
>         _minimizer in min.o
>         __ZNK11MinFcnCosmoclERKNSt3__16vectorIdNS0_9allocatorIdEEEE in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__14endlIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_ in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE5flushEv", referenced from:
>         _minimizer in min.o
>         __ZNK11MinFcnCosmoclERKNSt3__16vectorIdNS0_9allocatorIdEEEE in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__14endlIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_ in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6sentryC1ERS3_", referenced from:
>         __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6sentryD1Ev", referenced from:
>         __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__14coutE", referenced from:
>         _minimizer in min.o
>         __ZNK11MinFcnCosmoclERKNSt3__16vectorIdNS0_9allocatorIdEEEE in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__15ctypeIcE2idE", referenced from:
>         _minimizer in min.o
>         __ZNK11MinFcnCosmoclERKNSt3__16vectorIdNS0_9allocatorIdEEEE in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__14endlIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_ in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__16localeD1Ev", referenced from:
>         _minimizer in min.o
>         __ZNK11MinFcnCosmoclERKNSt3__16vectorIdNS0_9allocatorIdEEEE in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc in min.o
>         __ZNSt3__14endlIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_ in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__18ios_base33__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrowEv", referenced from:
>         __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc in min.o
>     "__ZNSt3__18ios_base5clearEj", referenced from:
>         __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc in min.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: Yes, please show the error message.  The `-dryrun` option applied described at http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-compiler-linking-mixed-fortran-cc-applications-in-version-9x-or-higher might help you locate a missing library.

Comment: I just printed the error message. I will take a look at the link you wrote. Thanks

Comment: Adding the -dryrun worked. Not only showed the paths, but also fixed the linking problem. Can you write an answer with a short explanation about this flag so I can give you the proper acknowledgments (and points) for that?

Comment: No, -dryrun did not fix the problem - it just shows you what commands it would execute without actually doing the link. Please bring your question to http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x

Comment: That is true. I was fooled because make clean did not erase the exec.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution is to add -lc++ to the link flags:

```
F90CRLINK = -cxxlib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -lMinuit2 -lc++
```